# code compile with java5 deploying on maching running java6

Tags: java, migration

I have a web application(client/server) which is currently deployed on tomcat 5.x. The code was compiled using jdk5 and deployed on machine running java5(jre).

Now i have to migrate the web application on new machine running java6. What are the possible problems that can happen during the migration process? Can I simply deploy the war compiled with jdk5 on a machine a machine running tomcat5.x & java6.

Comment: Yes, JDK is always backward compatible. I think you shouldn't face any issues.

Comment: @PradeepSimha i guess OP is asking other way around

Comment: @sansix as far as I understood, OP is saying he has compiled in JDK 5 and he should now run on JDK 6. And it is possible, but vice-versa is not possible.

Comment: @PradeepSimha oh yeah, my bad. and yes you are correct on your points